# Jquery selecting checkboxes that are checked is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the values of all checked checkboxes in a div and setting an inputbox's value with the values of the checked checkboxes.

my code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table-striped">
 <div id="checkboxlist">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="S"/>Sausages</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="N"/>Noodles</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="W"/>Wurst</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="E"/>Eggs</td>
   <td><button type="button" id="getresultbutton">Add items</button></td>
  </tr>
 </div>
</table>
   <div>    
    <input type="text" id="results">
   </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#getresultbutton").on("click", function(){
  var chkArray = [];
   $("#checkboxlist input:checked").each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
   });
   var selected;
   selected = chkArray.join(',');
    if(selected.length > 1){
      $("#results").val(selected);
    }else{
     alert("Please select atleast one of the checkboxes");  
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if my jquery selection of the elements is the issue or something else.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/avy1mdvr/

Comment: can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: Well, one issue is that your HTML is invalid.

Comment: You cannot put an `<div>` element inside of a `<table>`

Comment: Must...resist...urge...to reorder those menu items so their `value`s read "NSEW"...

Comment: @FrayneKonok Ive updated my question to include a fiddle

Comment: @jasonwarford Should i rather give the table an ID and use that?

Comment: @Bruno Well, I made a local testing and give a answer, have a look.

Comment: Works fine if you fix the invalid HTML https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cpLh9sLf/

Comment: @j08691 If by "fine" you mean "select at least **two** items."

Comment: @Draco18s - Yeah, he also needs to change the length to 0 `selected.length > 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is fine, its work for me when i did some change, have a look.

I just format your HTML Code and add a document ready function in jquery. also update the condition where it is invalid for selecting at least one of the checkboxes. is should be 0.

**Modified Script:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#getresultbutton").on("click", function(){
        var chkArray = [];
        $("#checkboxlist input:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(',');
        if(selected.length > 0){
            $("#results").val(selected);
        }else{
            alert("Please select at least one of the checkboxes");  
        }
    });
});
```

**Modified HTML:**

```
<div id="checkboxlist">
    <table class="table-striped">   
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="S"/>Sausages</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="N"/>Noodles</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="W"/>Wurst</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="E"/>Eggs</td>
        <td><button type="button" id="getresultbutton">Add items</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>    
    <input type="text" id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! The reason I chose this answer is because I have several tables and divs in my full code and this would be the ideal way for me to go about it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `div` element from the table, and give the `tr` the `checkboxlist` ID.

```
<table class="table-striped">
  <tr id="checkboxlist">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="S" />Sausages</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="N" />Noodles</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="W" />Wurst</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="E" />Eggs</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" id="getresultbutton">Add items</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="results">
</div>
```

You also need to use `> 0` when checking the length, since you want them to select at LEAST one. It also might be more readable to just check the length of your array, rather than the string.

```
if (chkArray.length > 0) {
...
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/skbnvhr8/)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**: remove the div inside the table

```
<table class="table-striped">
  <tr id="checkboxlist">
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="S"/>Sausages</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="N"/>Noodles</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="W"/>Wurst</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="E"/>Eggs</td>
   <td><button type="button" id="getresultbutton">Add items</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
   <div>    
    <input type="text" id="results">
   </div>
```

**Javascript**: pay attention to the length check (> 0, not > 1)

```
$("#getresultbutton").on("click", function(){
  var chkArray = [];
   $("#checkboxlist input:checked").each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
   });
   var selected;
   selected = chkArray.join(',');
    if(selected.length > 0){
      $("#results").val(selected);
    }else{
     alert("Please select atleast one of the checkboxes");  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can´t put a "div" tag in the table, it´s not HTMLy correct.

Second, if you want to get only the values of the input in the table, then give the table an id.

Finaly, you needed to make sure all the inputs are type checkbox, because it´s always good to control the variables you are calling, it´s not 100% necesary, but it will help you in the future when you program more dificult functions.

```
 $("#getresultbutton").on("click", function(){
  var chkArray = [];
  $("#tableCheck input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
   chkArray.push($(this).val());

  });
  var selected;
  selected = chkArray.join(',');
  if(chkArray.length > 0){
    $("#results").val(selected);
     }else{
 alert("Please select atleast one of the checkboxes");  
    }
  });
```

Hope it helps.

Fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/Yazsid/avy1mdvr/8/

Comment: thanks for your answer @Yazsid. I'll make note of your suggestions.